# A characterization of Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I'd like to check algebraically a result from Osborne and Rubinstein's *A Course in Game Theory*. Here's it:

> Let $G:=\langle N,(A_i),(u_i)\rangle$ be a finite strategic game. Then,
>   $$t:=(t_1,...,t_n)\in \Delta(A_1)\times...\times \Delta (A_n)$$ is a
>   Nash equilibrium of $G$ if and only if for every player $i\in N$, every pure
>   strategy in the support of $t_i$ is a best response to $t_{-i}$.

The proof presented in the book is the following:

> First suppose that there is an action $a_i$ in the support of $t_i$
>   that is not a best response to $t_{-i}$ . Then by linearity of $U_i$
>   in $t_i$ player $i$ can increase his payoff by transferring
>   probability from $a_i$ to an action that is a best response; hence
>   $t_i$ is not a best response to $t_{-i}$.

I know $U_i:\Delta(A_1)\times...\times \Delta (A_n) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $$U_i(s):=\sum_{a\in A}u_i(a)\prod_{j=1}^ns_j(a_j)$$ is linear but I didn't understand that transfer of probability. So I could not formalize the demonstration. If someone could help me, I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As usual mlc has a lovely answer, but something else to consider is what the geometry of each player's maximization problem looks like.  Conditional upon a choice of $t_{-i}$, $i$'s maximization problem is of an affine objective (so its level sets are linear) over a convex domain, so it's argmax necessarily contains some extremal points of the domain and the whole argmax is a convex combination of these points.  Now, if $t_i$ puts non-zero weight on any extremal point of the domain not in the argmax, it is suboptimal because it is not a convex combination of the extremal points in the argmax!

Answer (score 2):

An example might help. Consider the following simple game, where only the payoffs of player 1 are shown
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
& L & R \\
T & 2 & 0 \\
B & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}$$
Suppose player 2 is playing $L$, while Player 1 is playing $T$ with probability $p<1$ and $B$ with probability $1-p >0$. (Note that $B$ is not a best response for Player 1.)

Using this strategy, his expected playoff is 
$$2p + 1(1-p) = 1 + p$$
which is of course increasing in $p$. So Player 1 can increase his payoff by transferring probability from $B$ to $T$ by increasing $p$.

If you want to be more formal, interpret a "transfer" as replacing $p$ with $p^\prime = p + \varepsilon$, where $0< \varepsilon \le 1-p$. Then compare Player 1's payoff using $p$ versus using $p^\prime$.